# Use Recently Added Lead Object Id to Open Primary Tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender

Simplifying/Clarifying Question:

- Command button invokes method to insert lead object.
- Need to use a console tab method to open the newly inserted lead
  object.
- How do I pass the id back from the lead insert method?

---

I have a `<apex:commandButton action="{!createLead}" oncomplete"openLeadPrimaryTab()">.`

The createLead method inserts a lead object and sets the get-set variable, myLeadId, to the newly inserted lead object id after it has been inserted.

In the `openLeadPrimaryTab()` js function on the VFP, I am trying to open a primary tab based on `myLeadId`, but `console.log` shows that variable is not being passed. However, the lead is being created and the variable within the controller is being set, confirmed by `system.debug`. The tab is opening, but it is not opening to the id of the lead because it is not being passed back to the VFP.

I am calling the apex variable in js with `'{!myLeadId}'`

I have tried rerendering different containing components to see if that will get the variable, but to no success.

I'm assuming oncomplete, is not actually happening when the createLead method has completed, are action methods asynchronous, or is onComplete initiated after the click has completed, but not the method? Recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes back to another question I asked.

Javascript must be in an Output Panel component and directly rerendered as rerendering containing elements such as pageblock does NOT rerender the javascript.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!createObject}" value="Create New Record" reRender="outPanelIdGoesHere" oncomplete="openObjectInPrimaryTab()" />
```

Reference: [Return Boolean From Action Function called from JS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73424/return-boolean-from-action-function-called-from-js)